# Finding the Value of an Object Element within an Array

Tags: arrays, object, lua, lua-table

I have a table that im inserting into , The table holds Plate Values

How would i go about iterating over the table to return the following as true

```
function table.contains(table, element)
  for _, value in pairs(table) do
    if value == element then
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

My current table insert

```
for k, v in pairs(returnVehicleData) do
    platesAvailable = v.plate   
    newTable =  {['plate'] = platesAvailable}
    table.insert(vehiclePlateTable, newTable)
end
```

The data thats being returned

```
[{"plate":"47QVS009"},{"plate":"86KIE632"}]
```

I want to check the subsequent value after the : on both objects.

Comment: If your returned values are strings, you can try a string pattern such as `:"(.-)"` with `string.gmatch` to iterate over the results.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this and getting it to work

```
newValueTable = {}
    for Key = 1, #tabledPlate, 1 do
            table.insert(newValueTable, tabledPlate[Key].plate)
        end
```

Because the elements are part of an even bigger table of data , they dont actually return as a string. But thank you for the suggestion Coordinate Newton